# Difference between using camel main and operating directly on context object

Tags: apache-camel

I am creating my first camel standalone application. I saw some examples for this. There seem to be two flavors:

- using Main class and do setup (adding routes...) on this then call
  Main.run()
- creating a DefaultCamelContext object and then call start() on it

What are the differences between both ways? In my case i create the Context in a separate class and because there is no method to set the context into main i have to use context directly.
but i want to know what main delivers in addition, probably i have to implement some additional stuff?!

Answer (score 2):

The difference is one is to make it easier to bootup a Camel app in a JVM and have it keep running etc. And the other is to start a context using its start method.

You can find more details here

- http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

And then the javadoc of the CamelContext and its start method

- http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html

Comment: thx, - in my case i would chose main but how to set my own context to be used in main?

Comment: what does "have it keep running etc" mean? is it more defficult to keep it running if context.start()/stop() is used?

Comment: read the links I provided. And notice the difference between the blocked run method, and non-blocked start method.

Comment: thx but this didn't helped much: "important: the start method is not blocked, see more details here". Here links to your first link but on this page is no occurence of "blocked".
On the other hand there are 2 documents:
http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone.html
this says use a context and start it and links to
http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html 
this says use main and run. Both documents doesn't contain anything about "blocked" or other differences, but "keep it running".
So on what kind of standalone/use case you suggest which approach?

Comment: @ClausIbsen Please consider updating the links. ATM the both links are dead.